# How to sort this type of complex 3d array in php

Tags: php, arrays, list, sorting

The array is like this (I am using PHP)

```
array(2){[0]=>
             {[0]=>"DEF"=>
                       {[0]=>"a",[1]=>"c",[2]=>"b"},
              [1]=>"ABC"=>
                      {[0]=>"f",[1]=>"d",[2]=>"e"}},
        [1]=>
            {[0]=>"DEF"=>
                      {[0]=>"h",[1]=>"i",[2]=>"g"},
             [1]=>"ABC"=>
                      {[0]=>"k",[1]=>"l",[2]=>"j"}
            }
        }
```

I wish to be sort it like the first entry i.e. [0] index has two entries DEF and ABC so it should be sorted ABC and DEF then in ABC also a b c should be sorted.

The final result should be this

```
array(2){[0]=>
             {[0]=>"ABC"=>
                       {[0]=>"d",[1]=>"e",[2]=>"f"},
              [1]=>"DEF"=>
                      {[0]=>"a",[1]=>"b",[2]=>"c"}},
        [1]=>
            {[0]=>"ABC"=>
                      {[0]=>"j",[1]=>"k",[2]=>"l"},
             [1]=>"DEF"=>
                      {[0]=>"g",[1]=>"h",[2]=>"i"}
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: What does this notation mean "[0]=>"ABC"=>"? Assuming the value at position [0] is "ABC", what position does "{[0]=>"d",[1]=>"e",[2]=>"f"}" come in? Is that the second position in the array? Is it a subarray of a key called "ABC"?

Comment: yea they are subarrays

there are 3 levels, feach index has a subarray and in that subarray each index further has a subarray

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a custom sort option.  Try this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

I haven't used it but I had found it previously and remember it existed.

Comment: I'm not able to define how to use this custom sort for the purpose i need.

Comment: As you pointed out, it's a complex 3d array, your average sort is not going to cut it.  You can write your own sorting algorithm or you can learn to use usort.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sort` will solve problem

```
   $a = array(
            array(
                 "ABC"=>array("d","e","f"),
                 "DEF"=>array("a","b","c")
                ),

           array(
                "ABC"=>array("j","k","l"),
                "DEF"=>array("g","h","i")
                )
           );

  sort($a);
  var_dump($a);
```

The result

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["ABC"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "d"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "e"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "f"
    }
    ["DEF"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "a"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "b"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "c"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["ABC"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "j"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "k"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "l"
    }
    ["DEF"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "g"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "h"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "i"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if the lengths of subarrays are different then it sorts according to the length of the subarrays instead of alphabetically